# how to make coin flip transform in css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So, I have an icon, a circle icon, I want to make this icon when it hovered it will has coin flip transform, just like https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html but it flip two times so it goes back to the first position.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="football.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.bg {
        padding: 6px 6px;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
    }

    .icon {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
      border: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
    }

    .icon img{
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto; 
    }

    .icon:hover {
        transform: translateX( -1px ) rotateY( 180deg );
    }
```

[image: this is the icon's first position]

[image: this is the position when it hovered]

so the transform is not soft like the example from the link, and when the first flip (or rotation) I want to change the icon with different image, but when the second rotate it will back to first image. Any suggestion? thanks before

Comment: why my image not displayed?

Comment: The image appears just fine for me, assuming that there are only two (i.e. both coins being displayed).

Comment: yeah its just two, thanks in my browser it didnt appear @RionWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the animation itself, the transition.

```css
.bg {
        padding: 6px 6px;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
    }

    .icon {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
      border: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
      /* TRANSITION HERE!! */
      -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: transform 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: transform 1s ease;
      -o-transition: transform 1s ease;
      transition: transform 1s ease;
      /* END OF TRANSITION */
    }

    .icon img{
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto; 
    }

    .icon:hover {
        transform: translateX( -1px ) rotateY( 180deg ); /* ALSO EXTRA TRANSFORM PROPERTIES ADDED FOR COMPATIBILITY*/
        -ms-transform: translateX( -1px ) rotateY(180deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translateX( -1px ) rotateY(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVjde.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helped.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an animation the following:

```
@keyframes flip_animation {
  from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

And add this animation you your CSS-Class

```
.icon:hover {
    animation-name: flip_animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) for more information about animations in CSS.

Comment: It does work, however this only animates the flip forwards and not the flip backwards, which is instantaneous in this case. See: https://jsfiddle.net/g3phq25y/1/

Comment: thanks for your help, I guess I have some options for it too.

Comment: OK :) happy coding!